# Why does my async method run twice in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

I want to load a static list data when entering indexScreen,but the list sometimes show twice the same content,sometimes not.

This is my list setting:`List<ListClass> listItems=List<ListClass>();`,ListClass is a simple class with on different attributes and a constructor.

I use `home:IndexScreen()` in main.dart to show Index page.

```
return MaterialApp(
              home: IndexScreen(),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              onGenerateRoute: router.generator,
              builder: EasyLoading.init(),
            );
```

And before this page build,it will update `listItems` using:

```
Future<bool> initUserAndIndex() async{
  if (curUserEmail==null) sharedGetData(USER_EMAIL).then((value) => curUserEmail=value.toString());
  print(curUserEmail);
  await UserTable().getUserInfo(curUserEmail).then((value){print("user ok");});
  await CollectionTable().getIndexList().then((value){print("Collection ok");return true;});
  return null;
}
```

buildPage:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Object>(
      future: initUserAndIndex(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting)
          {
            EasyLoading.show(status: 'loading...');
            // avoid no return,this cause a whiteborad transition,I don't know how to solve it,too.
            return Container();
          }
        else
          {
              EasyLoading.dismiss();
              return SafeArea(
                  child: Scaffold(
                    // the listItems is used in Body()
                    body: Body(),
                  ),
                );
            }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I run this app,and it prints twice user ok and Collection ok.But when I use ROUTER.NAVIGETE,it only prints once.

User Information is OK,but the list is such a great problem--the page shows twice content

I put my code at an order of relevance of this prblom,I think.Next I put my the two awaited funtion here:
User:

```
Future<bool> getUserInfo(String userEmail) async{
    await userCollection.where({'userEmail':userEmail}).get().then((res) async {
    //assign to the static variables
    return true;
    });
    return null;
}
```

Collection:

```
  Future<bool> getIndexList() async {
    listItems.clear();
    await listCollection.get().then((value){
      var v = value.data;
      for (var data in v) {
        //get data and package them,add after the listItems list.
        listItems.add(ListClass(header, content, userId, favorCount, wordCount));
      }
      return true;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to assign your future in your widget class, but not in the build method as [the documentation show](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), otherwise, everytime your build method is triggered, it will call again your FutureBuilder.

```dart
final Future<String> _calculation = Future<String>.delayed(
  const Duration(seconds: 2),
  () => 'Data Loaded',
);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DefaultTextStyle(
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    child: FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: _calculation, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
         // ...
      }
     ),
    ),
   }
```